# Rails find by has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am looking for a way to query a model based on children in a has_many through association.

I have 3 models:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :conversations_participants
   has_many :participants, through: :conversations_participants
end

class ConversationsParticipant < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :conversation
   belongs_to :participant, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :conversations_participants
   has_many :conversations, through: :conversations_participants
end
```

I need to find conversations where participants matches an array of ids.

This is what i have at the moment (not working):

```
Conversation.includes(:participants).where(participants: params[:participants])
```

Comment: Just curious ... is there a Participant model (and subsequent table)?

Comment: Nope, participant is the User model

Comment: @craig.kaminsky - that query will work.

Comment: Good to know. Will remove incorrect comment

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you just want the conversations, if so you can `joins`.

```
Conversation.joins(:participants).where(:users => { :id => params[:participants] } )
```

Otherwise, if you want to eager load the participants, use `includes`

```
Conversation.includes(:participants).where(:users => { :id => params[:participants] } )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array like this:

```
Conversation.includes(:participants).where(:id => params[:participants])
```

Assuming that `params[:participants]` is an array.

Comment: I think that'll test the conversation.id not the participants.id

Comment: Yea, that checks for conversation.id:/

Comment: I don't think you want to test conversation ids against user ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
Conversation.includes(:participants).where( 'conversation_participants.participant_id' => params[:participants])
```

assuming that participant_id is the foreign key of participants in the conversation_participants table